# Can Windows services invoke photo viewer using .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

Hi I am trying to build a windows services that can invoke windows photo viewer to pop up the images.
And it goes well when I run in debug mode in VS2019 and also .exe file, but when I install it on windows services the images won't pop up !!! I try to click "allow service to interact with desktop" up but nothing happened too. I believe this maybe some setting error on my service, can any one help me ? thanks a lot!

and this is my source code

```
 public void PopImage(string imagePath)
        {
            using (var photoViewer = new Process())
            {
                photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = imagePath;
                photoViewer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                photoViewer.Start();
            }          
        }
```

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths for the imagePath?

Comment: Hi @ThomasLuijken absolute path

Comment: Hi @EnergyBoy. The process executable is also an absolute path?

Comment: @ThomasLuijken Yes is absolute path too